# Defining a combined complex ability rule in Cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I have a complex rule that I can't seem to define, a user can read their own letters or if they have permission they can read letters of others that aren't linked to any type (if they are then the type controls who sees it).

```rb
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :letter_template
  has_one    :letter_template_type, through: :letter_template
end

class LetterTemplateType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :types
end
```

I have tried this, thinking it would cover it but looking at the resulting sql it does an "or (not letter matching rule)" instead of "and (not letter matching rule)".

```rb
can :read, Letter
cannot :read, Letter, letter_template_type: { types: { active: [true, false] } } # the active [true, false] is just to find any type
```

The other way I tried was with a block/scope but then it complains
"CanCan::Error:
       Unable to merge an Active Record scope with other conditions. Instead use a hash or SQL for read Letter ability."

```rb
can :read, Letter, Letter.without_type do |l|
  l.letter_template_type.nil? || l.letter_template_type.types.empty?
end
```

Can anyone help me define a rule for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
 can :read, Letter, [] do |l|
   l.letter_template_type.nil? || l.letter_template_type.types.empty?
 end
```

You also have to add `a user can read their own letters` condition in above block, may be it is `l.user == your_ability_user`.

Comment: Thanks for the response jon, I haven't had a chance to try yet but my first concern is that it won't work for an accessible_by call?

Comment: Yes, It works but `accessible_by` gives you all records. So to authorize the resource, you have to explicitly write `authorize! :show, @user`  in each method, and block conditions works.